# Reading NFC Tags with iPhone 6 / iOS 11

Tags: ios, nfc, rfid, iphone-6

Does anyone know if iOS 11 will enable or support reading/detecting RFID tags for the iPhone 6/iPhone 6+ device? Anyone have any details to share on this?

I want to read the URL'S present in NDEF tags.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, developers can't read NFC NDEF tags on iPhone6/iOS 11. It's only support iPhone7/7+ or above with Core NFC.

You can get more detail from Apple's document(Core NFC): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc

Comment: It would seem the iOS version is not enough, although no list of devices are mentioned in the core NFC docs, only the required iOS version. Same with background reading of tags. Only Xs & XR support this regardless of iOS version.